# can I checkout into another branch after git add without commiting the changes

Tags: git

I have made some changes to a file in branch1 and I used git add . to stage those changes. Now, if I checkout into branch2 and made some changes to a different file in branch2 and use git add. and if I checkout into branch1 again will my changes be visible to me?

Comment: Can't you check it?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823541/11261546)