# git change branch - leave changes

Tags: git

Changing a branch with git checkout usually takes uncommitted changes to the new branch (and tries to merge them in, or fail).

Sometimes I'm working in a feature branch, and I am not quite ready with whatever I'm working on to commit them, but need to switch branches because I need to work on something else.

If this is just a "quick look" stashing, changing branches there and back and unstashing works.

If this is something that requires more time (in some cases two days or even a week), stashing is not really a good option, as other stuff may get stashed, so it's not exactly straight-forward to find which stash I am looking for), and even after changing back to the old branch, sometimes I even forget that I had a half-solution already.
Committing everything as a "wip" commit, and then later soft-resetting or amending that would be an okayish workaround, but it's still a workaround, and again may be forgotten that a wip commit is there, messing up the git log, unless one again spends time and effort to rebase stuff.

So the question is:

Is it possible to change branches, without committing changes, and without taking them to the new branch? And when changing back, the changes would be there either staged or unstaged?

Comment: The wip commit to be later reset is my personal favorite, but depending on the repo size and other factors, you might prefer a multiple worktrees strategy. Let one worktree in its present state and work on another branch in an additional [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Comment: I've never used them, but worktrees might be able to do this.  But typically I will just either `git stash` or WIP commit, and there's nothing wrong with doing that.  (Note: stash itself makes 2 or 3 commits under the hood, so it's really a WIP commit in disguise).

Comment: I think you have 3 options: Commit as WIP, stash and have multiple working trees. My choise is always WIP commit, I don't think it's that luch more extra work, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823541/11261546) to see a bit of a workflow

Comment: You should look into using worktrees, then you can have multiple branches checked out at the same time in different directories, from the same local repository. And no, with 1 working folder, you can't check out a different branch and not bring your uncommitted changes. What should git do with them to keep them until you come back? That's what stashing is for.

Comment: `git worktree` is almost certainly your best approach here. Make sure your Git is at least version 2.15. For more background, see also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible using just `git branch`. You should, however, be able to use `git worktree` in order to have multiple versions of your repository checked out in different directories.

Here's a link to the documentation for `git worktree`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree