# Create a new branch B from branch A (not master) but changes in B also appear in A

Tags: git

My project has 2 branches:

```
* master
* A
```

I created branch `B` from branch `A` by `git checkout -b B A`. After that, I made some changes in `B`, however those changes also appear in branch `A`.

Is that a normal behavior of Git? What should I do if I want changes in `B` don't appear in `A`?

For more detail, I didn't commit the changes in `B`; and checkout to `A` show the changes.

Comment: That's not how branch works. If you commit your change in branch B they will not be visible in branch A. For these changes to be visible in A, you must first merge branch B in A. To better understand your problem, you need to write exact commands you've run, show their outputs and explain what are the symptoms that make think this unexpected behaviour is occuring.

Comment: Did you *commit* your changes on `B`? Because if not, it's expected that your changes are still here after you switch. Asking just in case.

Comment: @RomainValeri No I didn't commit it.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67823541/11261546) might answer your question  :)

Comment: Great catch, @RomainValeri! :+1: I would have assumed that the OP was talking about _committed_ changes right off the bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RomainValeri mentioned above, since I didn't commit the changes, it's the default behavior of Git to show these changes when I switch to another branch.